# Symfony | Differences between local server and web server

Tags: php, css, symfony, web, server

I've got some problems with Symfony 2.8 project. There are differences between my project on my computer (local server) and web server.

Here is my code:
TWIG:

```
     <div id="ContactForm" >
        {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {{ form_end(form) }}
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
#ContactForm{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

When I check effect in Chrome on my local server, eveyrthing is ok. Console shows good CSS:

```
#ContactForm {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
```

Unfortunately, when I transfer all my files to ftp web server, there are some differences. I don't know why by there is also an inline style and I don't know where is it come from and why there are differences between local and web server.

```
element.style {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
position: absolute;
top: 200vh;
} 


#ContactForm {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
 }
```

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Have you tried emptying your browser cache?

Comment: If you have SSH access to your application then move to your app and run this command `rm -fr var/cache` and run your form again

Comment: Use your developer tools to inspect the css and see what is applying the unwanted style

Comment: @ShahrozeNawaz: This isn't a good way to clean cache... This is how you clean cache: move to your project root directory, and run `php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=prod`. @wojciecho-nowaczyk: There can be a few reason, inline CSS that you missing, Javascript execution. What you provided as code won't help us find the problem.

Comment: Yeah @Preciel you are right in some ways but once I talk to Javier Eguiliz of Symfony and got this better way to clean up the cache :D

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot :) You were right, the problem was cache. I manually deleted all the files from the cache folder and everything works fine. Thanks :)